# Почему не распознается вводимый оператор(+,-,/,*) и тд

Tags: c, c++

Изучаю Си, помогите решить проблему

**Вот мой код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter 1 value:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nEnter 2 value:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("\nEnter action you want to do with entered values[+,-,/,*]");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    switch(c) {
    case '+':
        printf("%d", a+b);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%d", a-b);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d", a * b);
        break;
    case '/': 
        printf("%d", a/b);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nEntered operator is not valid");
        return main();
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Могу поспорить, _второе_ значение тоже вводится неправильно, потому что вы не выбираете `\n` из входного потока.

Comment: @VladD, при правильных данных (числа) все OK. `scanf()` писали достаточно прагматичные люди, он (кроме формата %c) пропускает пробелы, табуляции, ньюлайны и т.п.

Вот при ошибке форматного ввода он оставляет символ, на котором преобразование "сломалось" в потоке. И этот символ надо убирать.

 На практике надежней всего просто прочесть поток до конца строки (включительно).

Comment: @avp: Хм, в C++ не так :-) Тогда проблема в типа аргумента, да.

Comment: @VladD, по поводу типа для `c` (нужно char, а не int с заменой %d на %c) ему уже @brightside90 написал. 

Но это будет работать только для ввода операции без пробелов между ней и вторым операндом.

--

А что Вы имели в виду, когда написали, что в С++  не так? cin >> ?

--

Вообще-то, если не заморачиваться с проверками, то ввод операции (в формате ТС) можно написать так

     char c, strop[10];
     scanf ("%s", strop); c = strop[0];

Comment: @avp: Угу. `cin >>` (который является рекомендованным методом ввода с консоли в C++) не пропускает `\n`.

---
Нуууууу... `strop[10]` == buffer overflow == exploit. Вы же сами написали `fgets`.

Comment: @VladD, exploit (а скорее segmentation fault или что-то еще в таком духе) -- для обучения это в самый раз.

--

А у меня (g++ в xubuntu (думаю на других будет то же самое)) замечательно пропускает. Вот все остальные символы после введенного char-а (вместе с `'\n'`) останутся в потоке...

     ...
     cin >> d1 >> d2 >> c;
     cout << d1 << c << d2 << '\n';
     ....
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    Enter op1 op2 cop: 22 333   
      +  
    22+333
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$

Comment: Казалось бы, простой вопрос..

Comment: @avp: а если вводить через Enter все три? Составить эксплоит не особо сложно, атакующий ведь контролирует адрес возврата. Первая же ссылка в гугле: http://www.insidepro.com/kk/011/011r.shtml

Comment: @VladD, вот все три и даже с Enter-ом перед ними

    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    Enter op1 op2 cop: 
    
    11
    12
    
    *
    11*12
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ 

без проблем.

--

По поводу переполнения буфера -- ну, понятно, я за надежное программирование. Тут самый простой вариант. В комментарии к ответу @brightside90, более правильный. 

--

@brightside90,

    Казалось бы, простой вопрос..

конечно, простой. Сложные тут так активно не обсуждают... (а жаль).

Comment: @avp: вот вам пример: http://ideone.com/m81g5R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте переменную с типа char и поменяйте ваш scanf("%d", &c); на scanf("%c", &c);

**UPD:** для корректной работы кода необходимо чистить поток ввода. Я больше ориентируюсь в С++, в С - меньше, но нужную вещь всегда можно нагуглить :)

```
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
```

Как я понял - это нужно добавить после первого и второго ввода, если я не прав, просветите, пожалуйста.

**UPD2:** странно, прогоняю код в 10 студии - всё работает.
Прогоняю [тут](http://ideone.com/CZgB8U) - не работает.

Comment: Чистить надо не всегда. Если `scanf` отработал нормально (вернул ожидаемое число, подробнее `man scanf`), то ничего чистить не надо.

А ввод данных у ТС, я бы упростил:

    char inbuf[LINE_MAX], operation[LINE_MAX];
    printf("Enter two integer values and operation [+,-,/,*]: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fgets(inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), stdin)) {
       int op1, op2, c, rc = sscanf(inbuf, "%d %d %s", &op1, &op2, operation);
       if (rc == 3) { 
         c = operation[0]; // это будет первый не пробел после операндов !!!
         ...
       } else 
         puts("Invalid input);
      ......

Comment: @brightside90 только вот никакой код символа при `scanf("%d", &c);` не вводится.

Comment: @brightside90, а чего Вы удивляетесь. Вы читаете в `c` следующий символ (прямо скажем байт) после второго операнда. 

У Вас это `'\n'`. Для формата `scanf("%c"...)` все правильно. Если хотите пропустить пробелы между элементами ввода, то читайте `"%s"` (см. мой комментарий).

Comment: @alexlz согласен, с этим напорол

Comment: @VladD, там комментарии кончились.

Посмотрел на пример ideone.com. Вы хотели продемонстрировать, что С++ is ugly (RMS) или terrible (Linus) язык? 

В принципе во многом с их оценкой крестов я согласен (по крайней мере с input/output) и сам предпочитаю чистый Си.

В коде на ideone проблема в смешивании cin >> (оставляет '\n' в потоке) с getline() (читает все до '\n'). 

Наверное тот формат правильно читать так -- число через cin >>, а потом в цикле getline(), пока не прочтем что-то не только из пробелов. Далее повторяем.

Comment: @avp: Скорее ugly. Смешивание всех возможных стилей ввода прекрасно работает в C#, C++ мог бы как-нибудь подружить свои собственные функции. Без `getline` обойтись нельзя, т. к. `cin >>` он не умеет читать строки, содержащие пробелы.

Comment: Проще всего вводить символ, как советует @brightside90, но непосредственно перед этим очистить входной поток

    fflush(stdin);

т.к. scanf оставляет символы в буфере. Переменная c может остаться типа int,

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a, b;
    unsigned char c;
    printf("Enter 1 value:");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("\nEnter 2 value:");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ); //Очистка от мусора
    printf("\nEnter action you want to do with entered values[+,-,/,*]");
    c = getchar();

    printf("%c\n", c);

    switch(c) {
    case '+':
        printf("%d", a+b);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%d", a-b);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d", a * b);
        break;
    case '/': 
        printf("%d", a/b);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nEntered operator is not valid");
        return main();
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Просто и понятно. если scanf("%c",&c); "автозаполняется", значит нужно сделать так чтобы заполнилось только то что нам нужно. 
обычно остаются всякие '\n' поэтому добавляем 

while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );

и всё это дело очищаем.

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, тогда уж getche и не надо printf после него

Comment: Действительно, если не зацикливаться на чтении всей тройки одним `scanf()`, то для чтения символа операции после того, как прочли оба операнда, вот такой код:

    int c; // int это важно
    ...
    while(isspace(c = getchar())); // пропустит лишние пробелы, ньюлайны и т.п.
    switch (c) {
    case EOF:
        .... // м.б. стоит обработать специально

IMHO выглядит вполне привлекательно