# Чтение строк из файла

Tags: файлы, строки, c++

Вот пункт меню на С++ который считывает данные из файла; префиксы переменных: с=char/string, i=int. Но он пропускает строку считывания дисциплины и записывает дисциплину в переменную вид ну и поне.... подскажите как избавиться от этой проблемы или что я делаю не так?

```
case 8:
{
    fflush(stdin);
    ifstream o("base.txt");
    if(!o)
    {
        throw "Файл не найден";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        o>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            getline(o,a[i].cDiscipline);
            getline(o,a[i].cVid);
            o>>a[i].iDate;
            o>>a[i].iMonth;
            o>>a[i].iYear;
            o>>a[i].iCabnumber;
            o>>b[i].iQues;
            for(int j=0;j<b[i].iQues;j++)
            {
                getline(o,b[i].cQuesmas[j]);
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n-Загружено-\n"<<endl;
    }
    break;
}
```

добавил getline(o,dummy); в самом начале цикла и все заработало корректно. спасибо avp!!!

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что Ваша проблема сегодня уже рассматривалась в комментариях к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/290760)

Конечно, Вы **не описали** формат данных, но судя по описанным симптомам, граница цикла `n` находится в отдельной строке.

Оператор `cin >> n;` считывает цифры и преобразует их в число, а следующий за ними `'\n'` оставляет во входном потоке. Его-то и читает (получая пустую строку) первый вызов `getline()`.

Далее очевидно.

Просто везде после cin >> и перед getline(), который должен читать с новой строки, вставляйте еще один getline(), скажем, в string dummy.

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает корректно